# Cython: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h file or directory not found

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Making myself familar with Cython, I get an error message after running the file `setup.py`:

```
numpy/arrayobject.h file or directory not found
```

After reading in stackoverflow about similar problems, I added:

```
include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
```

in the setup.py's setup command but this didn't work in my case. I looked in the directory that is stored in the np.get_include variable and indeed it doesn't contain such a file: it only contains another folder called numpy which in turn contains two files: multiarray_api.txt and ufunc_api.txt

Then I searched for the file `arrayobject.h` in my whole system but without success. Thus I reinstalled numpy without any improvement.

So I would like to ask if someone could help me either installing the file `arrayobject.h` or if someone would have another idea how to import numpy into my system.

I am sorry if I didn't provide enough background information - I will provide it if someone would tell what information is missing.

I use:

> Opensuse 13.2; Python 2.7.8; Numpy 1.10.4-110.1-x86_64; Cython 0.23.4-77.1-x86_64

Comment: You need the numpy-devel package

Comment: Thank you, DavidW, your tip solved my problem!

Comment: @DavidW You should post this as an answer (even if it's trivial, the question can be marked as answered)

Comment: @Snorfalorpagus I've marked it as a duplicate instead (although the duplicate I found isn't perfect the answer is basically the same so I think it's fair)